# is hoisting not followed by react js Proptypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes, hoisting

Version 1: Below code works fine as it is showing me Proptypes warning in console.

```js
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

    function SayHello({ firstName, lastName }) {
      return (
        <div>
          Hello {firstName} {lastName}!
        </div>
      )
    }
    SayHello.propTypes = {
      firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      lastName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }

    const element = <SayHello firstName={false} />
    
    ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6.1/prop-types.js"></script>
```

Version 2: This code does not show Proptypes warning in console because i've placed `SayHello.propTypes` after `const element`

```js
 const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

    function SayHello({ firstName, lastName }) {
      return (
        <div>
          Hello {firstName} {lastName}!
        </div>
      ) 
    }
    
    const element = <SayHello firstName={false} />
    
    SayHello.propTypes = {
      firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      lastName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement)
```

```html
 <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6.1/prop-types.js"></script>
```

Shouldn't both of these versions produce the same warning in console?

I thought according to js hoisting it would not make any different if the order of these declarations change.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Not everything gets hoisted - the function definition will, but assigning a property to it won't.

Comment: Both, function SayHello(){} and SayHello.propTypes are above ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement).
@jonrsharpe are you saying that SayHello.propTypes will not be available to SayHello during the execution of ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement)?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, but the warning on prop types is caused by the call to `createElement` (i.e. `const element = <SayHello firstName={false} />`), not `render`.

Comment: So, Is it like one cannot set the propTypes of SayHello once it gets created by React.createElement?

Comment: You can set them, but until and unless `createElement` gets called again there's no point having done so.